# how to use Mapbox-gl-geocoder in ionic

Tags: ionic4, mapbox-gl-js

I want to use geocoding in ionic-4 using mapbox.

```
import { MapboxGeocoder } from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder';
```

But I have the error:

```
Cannot find module '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder'
```

How to import MapboxGeocoder in ionic.

Comment: What `mapbox` dependencies have you added?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import * as MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder';
```